# Select non NA values in match when matching columns

Tags: r, match, subset, col

I have two `data.frame`s, `aa` and `bb`:

```
    aa <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(letters[1:4]),"d","d", "e","e"), Name = c("Dave", "Charlie", "Ella", NA,"Timothy","James",NA, "Bob"))
aa
  ID    Name
1  a    Dave
2  b Charlie
3  c    Ella
4  d    <NA>
5  d Timothy
6  d   James
7  e    <NA>
8  e     Bob

bb <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:5]),Name = 0)

 bb
  ID Name
1  a    0
2  b    0
3  c    0
4  d    0
```

I want to fill `bb$Name` by matching `bb$ID` with `aa$ID` so that I get the earliest name in the alphabet (in this case `James`):

```
 ID    Name
1  a    Dave
2  b Charlie
3  c    Ella
4  d   James
5  e    Bob
```

However, if I try `bb$Name <- aa[match(bb$ID,aa$ID),2]` I get:

```
bb

     ID    Name
1  a    Dave
2  b Charlie
3  c    Ella
4  d    <NA>
5  e    <NA>
```

Do you think some if statement code along the lines of: if there are more than 1 of the same values in `aa$ID`, and if one of those values are `NA`, then select the one that is of earlier alphabetical order to match with. So the `d` value in bb$Name would be `James`

I understand I could subset the original data but I don't want to do that in my actual data as the information that `aa$Name` has an `NA` value is important

Comment: Try with `order` before the `match` i.e. `aa1 <- aa[order(aa$ID, is.na(aa$Name)),];aa1[match(bb$ID,aa1$ID),2]`

Comment: I realised my question was too simplistic for the answer you gave (thank you btw). I have edited accordingly. It comes down to not wanting to permanently wanting to change the order of `aa`

Comment: In the edited one, why it is selecting 'James' over 'Timothy'?

Comment: Because I want it to select the one that's name is earlier in the alphabet

Comment: In that casse, do `aa1 <- aa[order(aa$ID, is.na(aa$Name), aa$Name),]`

Comment: If you try `aa[, .(sort(Name, na.last = T)[1]), by = .(ID)]`

Comment: @Titolondon, I get this error if I try your code: `Error in `[.data.frame`(aa, , .(sort(Name, na.last = T)[1]), by = .(ID)) : 
  unused argument (by = .(ID))`

Comment: Why is `bb` relevant to your problem?

Comment: @akrun, thank you, that works. However, my data is a bit more complex than that, and I'm worried about what will happen to its structure (have edited accordingly) - is there a way of throwing the `NA` values to the end of the rows in `aa1`? I think that would solve my problem

Comment: @Bonono Based on the examples you showed, my code is working `aa1[match(bb$ID,aa1$ID),2]
#[1] Dave    Charlie Ella    James   Bob`

Comment: Or using `data.table` `setDT(bb)[na.omit(setDT(aa)[order(ID, Name)]), NameN := i.Name, on = "ID"]`

Comment: Ouch! sorry. It works with data.table. I forgot to precise it.

Comment: @akrun, I understand the code works but I'm asking you if you know of a way that would put the `NA` values at the end of `aa1`? This is a separate question to filling in `bb$Name`

Comment: The `aa[order(-!is.na(aa$Name)),]` gets the NA at last

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ok to create a temporary copy of aa?

```
tmp <- aa[!is.na(aa$Name),]
tmp <- tmp[order(tmp$Name),]
bb$Name <- tmp[match(bb$ID,tmp$ID),2]
bb
```

This gets you the result you wanted.